# Activate JNDI on Windows ActiveMQ : configuration?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm tring to activate JNDI on Windows.
My ActiveMQ is installed under `C:\apache-activemq-5.14.5-bin\apache-activemq-5.14.5`.
I've created the `jndi.properties` in `conf/` with the same example of https://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html, just uncommenting `connectionFactoryNames`.
I start with `bin\activemq.bat start` (so `jndi.properties` is in the %ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH) it but there's no JNDI listener :
[image]

What is missing ? I find that Apache documentation is poor.

Comment: Sorry Justin, and thank you for your answer, I see clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ doesn't provide a *server-side* JNDI implementation. It has no "JNDI listener."

As [the documentation states](https://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html), ActiveMQ provides...

> a simple JNDI `InitialContextFactory` which can be used to lookup JMS `ConnectionFactory` objects as well as `Destination` objects.

This is done *on the client*. You put `jndi.properties` on the classpath of *the client* and when the client calls `new InitialContext()` it will use the configured `InitialContextFactory` implementation (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`) to perform its JNDI lookups. The client will then be able to lookup any of the implicit or explicitly configured `ConnectionFactory` and `Destination` objects.

Putting `jndi.properties` on the classpath of ActiveMQ does nothing for the broker itself.